# Application scope bean impacting performance

Tags: java, scope, managed-bean

I have an application that uses an application scope bean to load a set of data when the app starts up. This used to be done in a session scope bean, but was taking way too long, so I decided to do it in an application scope bean.

Now that I've done this, the part that was taking long(the first screen's loading) is nice and fast, but the rest of the application is terribly slow.

Does anyone know of any instances in which an application scope bean could negatively impact the performance of an application?

Comment: Make sure the 'loading of the set of data' happens only once and during the app startup.

Comment: @adarshr I put logs around it, to tell me when loads the data - I'm 100% positive that it only loads once.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that you did not modify anything else except moving the "load a set of data" to a `@ApplicationScoped` bean. Data from a database - query size?
How is the `@ApplicationScoped` bean accessed from the `@SessionScoped` beans, maybe there is the bottleneck. You should definitely add some code to show:

- How the data was loaded in the `@SessionScoped` bean before
- How the data is loaded in the `@ApplicationScoped` bean now
- How the data loaded from the `@ApplicationScoped` bean is accesses (by the `@SessionScoped` beans?)

Otherwise its quite difficult to determine what's slowing down your application.